# Infinite allocation memory app crashes

Tags: c++, windows, memory, allocation

I have a code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            new int;
        }
        catch(std::exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, when I run this code under Linux, my computer freezes when memory is end (as expected), but when I'm on Windows, my app crashes after allocating 3 gb of memory (usually I have 1 gb used, and 16 in total). Why it crashes? How to prevent this?

When I replace `new int` with `malloc(1)`, after allocating these 3 gb, memory isn't going to allocate more

Comment: How does is "crash?"  What are you trying to do,exactly?

Comment: Your `catch` is useless. You can't call `new` after a `bad_alloc` exception is thrown, and no other exceptions could possibly be occurring in that context.

Comment: Additionally, a compiler could see that you don't actually store the `new` return value and optimize away the invocation.

Comment: Also exceptions should be caught by const reference *not* by value.

Comment: looking at your code i do not even understand what you are intending to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it crashes under Windows is simply that you compile it as x86 and not as x64 executable. x86 executables have a limitation of 3GB of RAM because it runs out of adresses. Under Linux you compile 64bit by default (on a 64bit machine using g++), so it does not crash here but freezes the system, as the system is using the swap space after its out of RAM which is damn slow. If the SWAP also fills up, your system is simply going down. Compile the Windows version as 64bit and see what happens then.

My assumption for this text is you have a 64bit machine (otherwise you wouldnt be able to use those 16GB of RAM).

Now, when using `malloc` instead of `new`, your program wont crash, as malloc has error states. It will simply give you a `NULL` pointer back as it is not able to allocate more memory. `new` does not.

Comment: Yes, when I used g++ 64bit it worked! Please say me, when my Linux freezed when only 80% of memory when occupied? It doesn't happen with WIndows

Answer (score 0):

Why are you expect that program will freeze? It is just one of possible behavior, not the best and not the worst (most likely worst, to be honest ). C++ standard has plenty of places with undefined behavior. This is obviously one of this places, because it depends on underlying OS layer.

Try to print something in `catch` block. Thus you will know when the application crashes - before or after catching an exception. Allocate a bigger blocks, because now in case of total lack of memory C++ runtime may not work properly and it may lead to crash.

Comment: This would more likely result in a race condition. What happens first? Output or freeze? Maybe the output may cause the freeze at this point, too.